# print delay with pexpect: select returning stdin when no data ready to read

Tags: python, select, terminal, stdin, pexpect

Using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I'm running Python in a subprocess. When the program below is run, I have to hit a key before the `>>>` prompt is displayed.

I previously was using a naive version of pexpect, but switched hoping this would fix the problem. In this naive version, the problem was that `select.select()` returned stdin as ready to read when in fact it wasn't, as a blocking read on stdin was attempted, blocking the program until I hit a key. I suspect the same thing is happening here.

How do I prevent this behavior?

This is as minimal a working example as I've been able to come up with so far:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import termios
import tty

import pexpect


def get_cursor_position(to_terminal, from_terminal):
    original_stty = termios.tcgetattr(from_terminal)
    tty.setcbreak(from_terminal, termios.TCSANOW)
    try:
        query_cursor_position = "\x1b[6n"
        to_terminal.write(query_cursor_position)
        to_terminal.flush()
        while from_terminal.read(1) != 'R':
            pass
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(from_terminal, termios.TCSANOW, original_stty)


def set_up_listener():
    def get_cursor_on_connect():
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        get_cursor_position(sys.stdout, sys.stdin)
        conn.send(b'done')
        conn.close()

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
    sock.listen(1)
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_cursor_on_connect)
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'inner':
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
        assert b'done' == s.recv(1024)
        sys.stderr.write('>>> ')
        sys.stderr.flush()
        while True:
            pass  # spin forever so daemon thread doesn't die
    else:
        set_up_listener()
        proc = pexpect.spawn(sys.executable, ['test.py', 'inner'])
        proc.interact()
```