# Select returns stdin when nothing to read, so print delayed with pty in Python

Tags: python, select, stdin, pty

After I run this script with Python 2.7.9 on OSX, the prompt `>>>` doesn't display until I hit a key. I believe this is because a select in pty is returning stdin as read to be read when there are no bytes on it to be read.

This script listens on a socket in one thread and in another runs the client version of the script in a subprocess in a pty. This client version connects to the server, causing it to do a cursor query, the recieves bytes on the socket and closes it closes the connection. The client process then prints a prompt and waits for input, but this prompt doesn't appear onscreen until a key is pressed because the parent process's tty code is waiting on a blocking read of stdin.

The question is directly related to [print delay with pexpect: select returning stdin when no data ready to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663269/print-delay-with-pexpect-select-returning-stdin-when-no-data-ready-to-read) – the different here is I'm not using pexpect, just pty from the standard library to simplify the example.

```
import pty
import socket
import sys
import termios
import threading
import tty


def get_cursor_position(to_terminal, from_terminal):
    original_stty = termios.tcgetattr(from_terminal)
    tty.setcbreak(from_terminal, termios.TCSANOW)
    try:
        query_cursor_position = "\x1b[6n"
        to_terminal.write(query_cursor_position)
        to_terminal.flush()
        while from_terminal.read(1) != 'R':
            pass
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(from_terminal, termios.TCSANOW, original_stty)


def set_up_listener():
    def get_cursor_on_connect():
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        get_cursor_position(sys.stdout, sys.stdin)
        conn.send(b'done')
        conn.close()

    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(('localhost', 1234))
    sock.listen(1)
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_cursor_on_connect)
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'inner':
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
        assert b'done' == s.recv(1024)
        sys.stderr.write('>>> ')
        sys.stderr.flush()
        while True:
            pass
    else:
        set_up_listener()
        pty.spawn([sys.executable, 'test.py', 'inner'])
```

Comment: what/ where are you running it on/from and what python version?

Comment: The behaviour you describe occurs when it tries to spawn the client by itself. Otherwise, if you start the client and the server separately, things go smooth.

Comment: Padraic - added, thanks - it's 2.7. Pynchia, yes that's correct - I only observe this behavior when the server runs the client in a pty. I've added a description of what the script does.